# How To Change CommandButton Color, PowerPoint VBA

Tags: vba, colors, powerpoint

I want to have the color of my CommandButton change to black when it is clicked. I am programming with VBA in PowerPoint. I have already tried this:

```
With ActivePresentation.Shapes("MyButton").Fill
    .Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End With
```

Of course, the above code should run on click.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow! I can't believe I thought of this so fast!
This is the code that works:

```
MyButton.BackColor = 0
```

It changes the background color to black!